# C++ - Static function using vector<derivedclass> don't find declared identifier

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, static-members, identifier, derived-class

while working on a personal project on a new language, I 've come across a annoying compiling time error where a static member of my constants.h (constants class) doesn't find the class name (Quark which is a derived class of Particle, those two in the same file "Particle.h") used in parameter...

Here is the compilation error output:

```
1>f:\bibliotheques\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\particlefuzzer\launcher\constants.h(41): error C2065: 'Quark' : undeclared identifier
1>f:\bibliotheques\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\particlefuzzer\launcher\constants.h(41): error C2923: 'std::vector' : 'Quark' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
1>f:\bibliotheques\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\particlefuzzer\launcher\constants.h(45): error C2065: 'Quark' : undeclared identifier
1>f:\bibliotheques\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\particlefuzzer\launcher\constants.h(45): error C2923: 'std::vector' : 'Quark' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
1>f:\bibliotheques\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\particlefuzzer\launcher\constants.h(45): error C3861: 'Quark': identifier not found
1>f:\bibliotheques\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\particlefuzzer\launcher\constants.h(45): error C2514: 'std::vector' : class has no constructors
1>f:\bibliotheques\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\particlefuzzer\launcher\constants.h(46): error C2663: 'std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc>::vector' : 8 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer
1>f:\bibliotheques\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\particlefuzzer\launcher\constants.h(50): error C2065: 'Quark' : undeclared identifier
1>f:\bibliotheques\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\particlefuzzer\launcher\constants.h(50): error C2923: 'std::vector' : 'Quark' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
1>f:\bibliotheques\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\particlefuzzer\launcher\constants.h(50): error C3861: 'Quark': identifier not found
1>f:\bibliotheques\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\particlefuzzer\launcher\constants.h(50): error C2514: 'std::vector' : class has no constructors
1>f:\bibliotheques\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\particlefuzzer\launcher\constants.h(51): error C2663: 'std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc>::vector' : 8 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer
```

Here the crashing code:
**constants.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include "Particle.h"

class constants
{
public:

    static enum nucl
    {
        proton = 0
        ,neutron = 1
    };

    static std::vector<Quark> getNuclVal(nucl type)
    {
        if (type == nucl::proton)
        {
            std::vector<Quark> result({ Quark(std::string("up")), Quark(std::string("up")), Quark(std::string("down")) });
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            std::vector<Quark> result({ Quark(std::string("up")), Quark(std::string("down")), Quark(std::string("down")) });
            return result;
        }
    };
// More functions and constants
};
```

**Particle.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "Entity.h"
#include "constants.h"

class Particle : public Entity
{
private:
// some stuff
public:
// some stuff
};

class Quark : public Particle
{
public:
    Quark(std::string &const);
};
```

and there is my Quark class definition in **Particle.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Particle.h"
#include "constants.h" 
#include <string>
#include "Entity.h"

Particle::Particle(std::string &const name, Size size)
: Entity::Entity()
, m_charge(0) //en e
, m_mass(0) //en electron Volt (eV)/c²
, m_Size(size)
, m_name(name)
{
};

Quark::Quark(std::string &const name) // declaration stuff
    : Particle(name, Size::Sub_Atomic)
{
    constants::quark type = constants::getQuarkByName(m_name);
    setMass(constants::getMass(type));
    setCharge(constants::getCharge(type));

}

// various stuffs
```

There is my precompiled header which include every sources I need in my program (to let you see compilation order) **stdafx.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>


// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
#include "Math.h"

#include "SciNumber.h"
#include "PhyEngine.h"
#include "Options.h"
#include "ConfigFile.h"
#include "Chameleon.h"
#include "Entity.h"
#include "Particle.h"
#include "constants.h"
```

I wonder if I need to separate my derived classes of Particle to specific files or not (It would add a lot of files..... T-T), what do you think about it?

here is my class diagram (open with Visual studio) to help you visualize the whole project: [download it here via my dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h3cqi1sfwpwhj1t/ClassDiagram1.cd?dl=0)

Comment: You have a circular include dependency. `constants.h` includes `Particle.h` which includes `constants.h`.

Comment: It simply means, that you created circular dependency. If you have such problems **now** (you "project" doesn't look like a big one for now) - good luck. Design comes first, then goes coding, not the other way.

Comment: "crash" refers to runtime failures, not compilation errors

Comment: What is in `Entity.h`? (no, I can't go to the site you linked to).  Second, why does `Particle.h` require an include of `constants.h`?  I see no use of anything in `constants.h` in the Particle.h file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular dependency in your headers. `Particle.h` includes `constants.h` and `constants.h` includes `Particle.h`. You'll need break the loop.

You get the error because when `Particle.h` is included, it'll at first include `constants.h`. Then `constants.h` will try to include `Particle.h`. `#pragma once` will prevent infinite recursion, but also means that rest of the `Particle.h` is not yet included before the contents of the `constants.h`. Thus the compiler complains about missing declarations.

You should be able to break the loop by breaking your headers and possibly classes into smaller ones*. The static member functions of `constants` are not strictly related to each other, are they? In fact, from what I've seen, it should probably be a namespace rather than a class**. Stuff in namespace can be conviniently declared in separate headers while a class must be defined entirely in one.

*Assuming you actually need to. If `Particle.h` doesn't depend on `constants.h`, then simply remove the include.

**I may be wrong about that since you didn't show the entire class.

Break off the part of `constants` that depends on `Quark` (and anything that depends on anything that depends on `Quark`, recursively) into another class in another header and don't include that one inside `Particle.h`. Or break off parts of `Particle.h` that depend on `constants.h` and don't include that one in `constants.h`.

`stdafx.h` also includes `constants.h` which in turn includes `stdafx.h`. You'll need to fix all circular includes.

Comment: Thanks ! really! :D I cleaned my include tokens, changed constants from class to namespace and moved his needed methods into particles.h. :D
After some corrections and adaptations, it compile great and works again! Really thanks a lot! ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try moving

```
#include "constants.h"
```

to the bottom of **Particle.h**. What currently happens is that **Particle.h** goes through **constants.h** before it has declared the types.

**constants.h** is not re-including particle.h because of pragma #once (without which you would have circular dependencies and nothing would work anyway).

You also don't need the `#include "constants.h"` in **stdafx.h** as it is already included in **Particle.h**

I hope this helps!

Comment: It's not a solution. The only solution is to remove circular dependency. Also, headers included in pre-compiled header should not have any dependencies or be dependent in a the same order they are included.

Comment: Yes, getting rid of the circular dependency is the best way. However, assuming that pragma #once works the same way as traditional header guards, this is not the problem here.
Regarding the includes in **stdafx.h** I am merely pointing out that it is *not necessary* not *wrong*

Comment: Yep, that is true. Good design is definitely different.